# The onNotification callback doesn't fire if an app is in background. Using cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, firebase-cloud-messaging

The `onNotification` callback doesn't fire after tapping on a notification while the app is in background.
The app goes to the foreground, but the JS event handler does not execute. Also, in the case of Android, there are no messages containing `FCMPluginActivity` in Logcat, therefore I think that the corresponding activity does not start.

Since we use meteor, Cordova version is fixed by Meteor version, and the newest meteor version has cordova-android v7.1.4 and cordova-ios v4.5.5, failing the requirements to use the latest version of `cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated`. So we use version 3.2.0.

How to reproduce (in case of Android):

1. Create new meteor app: `meteor create --full ./test-fcm`.
2. Add the plugin: `meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated@3.2.0`.
3. Add mobile-config.js file to the root, containing `App.info({id: "com.yourCompany.appId"});`.
4. Add google-services.json file to test-fcm/cordova-build-override/platforms/android/app/.
5. Start the app: `meteor run android`.
6. Connect Chrome DevTools to emulator and create `onNotification` event handler: `window.FCMPlugin.onNotification((data) => { console.log(data); });`.
7. Send notification with custom data from the firebase console.

Any advice will help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out we forgot to add `click_action` field to the FCM request payload (`"click_action":"FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY"`).

With this field in place `onNotification` works correctly.